# Yii thumbnail on focus enlarge

Tags: yii, onclick, thumbnails, image-enlarge

I have given a Thumbnail view to my page which is an extended widget of bootstrap want to make it onclick enlarge or onclick thumbnail image change. How may I set those two options in my widgets. I searched, but couldn't get the right one.

```
$this->widget(
'bootstrap.widgets.TbThumbnails',
array(        
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'template' => "{items}\n{pager}",
    'itemView' => '_thumb',        
    )     );
```

where the _thumb is my view file(php file).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this widget you can't. It is for creating a list of [thumbnails](http://www.cniska.net/yii-bootstrap/#tbThumbnails). If you want to enlarge them in eg a lightbox you have to install a lightbox extension and make it work with this thumbnails. It's the same for changing the images onclick.

Comment: I think those extensions are useful to fetch the folder images one by one with two different set of images folder. In my case I fetch all the images from the database url, so implementing such extension and maintaining two set of images is cumbersome!!